# add a password to a link for an IP camera in asp classic

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, passwords, ip, ip-camera

so i have the current code:

```
strconnectstring="http://camuser:mf@192.168.0."&strip&":"&strport&"/image/jpeg.cgi?profileid=1"
```

so the link provides the password(mf) and user(camuser)

the problem is that it works fine in chrome and firefox but in internet explorer it doesn't seem to work at all. any tips?

i tried to do it without any passwords but it keeps asking the password and you can't save it, it's not really possible to save all passwords on all the useraccounts.

thanks in advance!

Comment: A little more code for context would probably help, also clarifying is this [tag:asp-classic] or [tag:asp.net]? They are two very different things and will get you two very different answers.

Comment: see title ;) and it's all about the "user:password@" method but I've found it already, Microsoft thought it wasn't safe enough so the disabled the option. you just have to edit the registry

Comment: Then get rid of the asp.net tag if it isn't about asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had to change the register to allow the user:password method again

To disable the new default behavior in Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer, create iexplore.exe and explorer.exe DWORD values in one of the following registry keys and set their value data to 0.

```
    •   For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry key:
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
    •   For the current user of the program only, set the value in the following registry key:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
```